# If $A$ and $B$ are not countable. Is $A \cup B$ not countable and vice versa

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For infinite sets, if $A$ and $B$ are not countable. Does that imply that $A \cup B$ is not countable and vice versa. I don't know how to show this.

It would be great if someone shows how they would tackle this question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A \subseteq A \cup B$ so what can you say about the cardinality of the latter set?

As for the converse, think of adding a little to a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Recall two basic theorems about countable sets:

1. The union of two countable sets is countable.
2. Every infinite subset of a countable set is countable.